# How to add implicit spring social sign up for different role

Tags: spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I integrated spring social facebook login and signup in my spring mvc project and its working perfectly without role.
In this project I have two role **seeker and provider** , I want to add **implicit social sign up** for both role seeker and provider , for that I have two seperate view for both seeker and provider for sign in . if I click the Sign In button from seeker view then it should check seeker is register or not if not it will register seeker implicit . but the problem is **how we will assign seeker and provider role automatically** . how we know which view (seeker or provider) button clicked ......
**Thanx in advace**